# Button Header and Check box field in Gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header, rowcommand

I want a button in the Header of my Gridview and a checkbox field in the row of that header.

I was hoping the following code will work. However, this is not working. I just see "Remove" text in my header and when I click it nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
                    GridLines="None" OnRowCommand="Gridview2_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="fname" HeaderText="First Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="mname" HeaderText="Middle Name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="lname" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove">
                    <ItemTemplate>

                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkselect" runat="server" />

                    </ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:HeaderTemplate>

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Split">sort</asp:LinkButton>

                     </asp:HeaderTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns> </Gridview>
```

The Even for Row Command

```
protected void Gridview2_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Split")
        {
            Response.Write("I was clicked");
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: it working fine....you might didnt see the text only bcz of gridview hide....

Comment: I am not hiding it anywhere.

Comment: i means your Response.Write is hide behind gridView.....Instead of Response.wRITE try this..ScripManger.RegisterClientScript(this,this.GetType(),"hello","alert('hello')",true); u will see it will alert message when u click on button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong tab prefix. The header template is simply

```
 <HeaderTemplate> not <asp:HeaderTemplate>
```